# Limit number of recipients in an email - Google Apps

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-developer-tools

We are trying to Limit number of recipients in `To`, `CC` and `Bcc` fields using following regular expression, however not functioning as required. Please help.

Full headers / Recipient headers matches regex -  `([^@]*@){3,}`

Comment: Please post a clear ***INPUT*** and desired ***OUTPUT*** sample

Answer (score 0):

Without much to go on in your original post you I offer this rather bleak answer which will match 1, 2 or 3 email addresses that adhere to [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-base.org/rfc-5322.html):

```
(?:(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])[,;\s]*){1,3}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note: right click the image and select Open in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use against "Recipients header" in a Compliance policy in Google.

^[^@]*(\@[^|]*){6,}$